# Is it possible that a duplicate keypair can be created and used?

Tags: account, keypair

Solana_sdk::signature::Keypair is used to create the account address, this method is being used by everyone across the world and then the client program submit to the cluster.
So my question is, could it be that the same keypair is created by more than one person?
Then how does it made atomic in the complete network ?

Comment: it's very less probable in case of addresses having a secret key but with PDA's yes there is possibility of having dublicate keys

Comment: Are you saying that two keypair can have same public key but different private key?

Comment: PDA does not have private keys